# How to load vue components with promise?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a vue test file `test.vue` like this

```
<template>
    <div>
        {{a}}
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    data : () => {a:1},
    template: ...,
}
</script>
```

And I want to load it in the vue instance.

```
var vm = new Vue({
    el: ...,
    components : {
        'ti-test': () => import("./components/test.vue")
    },
   ...
});
```

but I get an error

```
vue.js:597 [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve async component: () => import("./components/test.vue")
Reason: SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

How can I get this to work?

Thanks

Comment: did you try `'ti-test': require("./components/test.vue")`?

Comment: where are you using promise in test.vue

Comment: Are you getting any errors from webpack?

Comment: Double-check to see if webpack is putting your components in the right place and you're publishing them correctly.

Comment: im not using webpack